# How to delay rendering of components on fetch request in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rendering

While fetching request how do I put rendering on hold?Because in my code I'm fetching request server on button click and also I'm rendering the fetched response after that.But rendering occurs before fetching so I'm getting undefined value when I mapped over the `responseData` within `render`.Following is my code

**updated**

**screen.js**

```
import { article } from "./data";
import PopupDialog from "react-native-popup-dialog";
import AddNewarticle from "./AddNewarticle";

class SecondScreen extends Component {
  state = { res: [] };
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.initialState = {
      modalVisible: false,
      Disable_Button: false,
      ViewArray: []
    };
    this.state = this.initialState;
    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);
    this.Array_Value_Index = 0;
  }
  Add_New_View_Function = () => {
    this.animatedValue.setValue(0);

    let New_Added_View_Value = { Array_Value_Index: this.Array_Value_Index };

    this.setState(
      {
        Disable_Button: true,
        ViewArray: [...this.state.ViewArray, New_Added_View_Value]
      },
      () => {
        Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 400,
          useNativeDriver: true
        }).start(() => {
          this.Array_Value_Index = this.Array_Value_Index + 1;

          this.setState({ Disable_Button: false });
        });
      }
    );
  };

  onPressButton() {
    onPressSubmit();
    Add_New_View_Function();
  }
  onPressSubmit() {
    fetch("xxxxx", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        url: this.state.url
      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        this.setState({
          res: responseData,
          loaded: true
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({ showLoading: true });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const AnimationValue = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],

      outputRange: [-59, 0]
    });
    let Render_Animated_View = this.state.ViewArray.map((item, key) => {
      if (key == this.Array_Value_Index) {
        return (
          <Animated.View
            key={key}
            style={[
              styles.Animated_View_Style,
              {
                opacity: this.animatedValue,
                transform: [{ translateY: AnimationValue }]
              }
            ]}
          >
            <Text />
          </Animated.View>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <View key={key} style={styles.Animated_View_Style}>
            {this.state.res.map(a => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("clicked")}>
                <CardSection>
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{a.title}</Text>
                  </View>
                </CardSection>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ))}
          </View>
        );
      }
    });
    return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 2 }}>{Render_Animated_View}</View>
        </ScrollView>

        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.7}
          style={styles.TouchableOpacityStyle}
          disabled={this.state.Disable_Button}
          onPress={() => this.popupDialog.show()}
        >
          <Image
            source={{
              uri:
                "https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Floating_Button.png"
            }}
            style={styles.FloatingButtonStyle}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <PopupDialog
          ref={popupDialog => {
            this.popupDialog = popupDialog;
          }}
          dialogStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#f2ddd5", height: 100 }}
          containerStyle={{ zIndex: 50, elevation: 100 }}
          overlayBackgroundColor="#000"
          dismissOnTouchOutside={true}
        >
          <View>
            <TextInput
              style={{ height: 40 }}
              placeholder="Enter the url you want to save!"
              multiline
              onChangeText={url => this.setState({ url })}
              underlayColor="#fcc9b5"
            />

            <Button title="Ok" onPress={() => this.onPressButton.bind(this)} />
          </View>
        </PopupDialog>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default SecondScreen;
```

**updated**

Currently I'm fetching `article` (json data containing a list of articles) and rendering some cards with the fetch response i.e, title is displayed within cards.At the end of it there will be an add button on clicking that button a popup will be displayed, within that there will be field to paste article's link and by clicking on `tick` icon it will be send to server , and I will get a json response back (`res`). So I want the data within this `res`  to be rendered and show card list with the data within `res`. How can this be done?For now I've tried several methods.So there will 2 rendering where do I call this `renderArticle`?Please help..Hope you understand what I'm saying..Any queries please feel free to ask..

Comment: Try with conditional rendering, change a state in your setState and use {this.state.rendered && Your HTML to render}

Comment: Sorry can you give me an example code for that?

Comment: Please share a sandbox with your code.

Comment: I've updated my question with more info please do help

Comment: could you format your code, please. its showing syntax error

Comment: In btw try your setState like `this.setState({  res:responseData }, () => this.setState({loaded: true}););` and in render try `{this.state.loaded && this.renderArticle()}` . keep `loaded:false` by default

Comment: I've a doubt can I give multiple actions for `onPress` of Icon. I want something like this `onPress={ () => onPressSubmit(); this.add_new_function();}` how to perform this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177402/discussion-between-aravind-s-and-anu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF res is an array of objects

```
// res = [{title:'article1'},{title:'article2'}] ] 

renderArticle(){
  if(this.state.res.length){
    return this.state.res.map(newarticle =>
      // Your code
    )
  }else {
    return null
  }
}
```

IF res is in below form

```
res = {
  article1Detail: {title:'article1'}, 
  article2Detail: {title:'article2'} 
}


renderArticle(){
  if(Object.values(this.state.res).length){
    return Object.values(this.state.res).map(newarticle =>
      // Your code
    )
  }else {
    return null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { article } from "./data";
......
.....
onPressSubmit() {
     this.setState({ showLoading: true});
    fetch( // api info})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
            showLoading: false,
            res:responseData
        })
     })
    .catch(() => {
      this.setState({showLoading: false});
    })
  }

render() {
  return () {
    if (this.state.showLoading) {
      // return spinner
    }

    return this.renderArticle();
  }
}

  renderArticle(){

    /**
    check if state has data then 
    render content or render null 
    (can happen when api fails)
    **/
  }
```

Comment: I tried this but their is some syntax error.Also when i set state within catch it will replace the value which holded previously right?So i don't get the `json` data within render.

Comment: syntax error? I wrote this code on the fly to explain. I am not sure its working or not. Can you share the error? 

In catch you don't update your data but just change the loading state, else your component will keep on showing spinner

Comment: I've updated my question please do check.I'm getting `map of undefined`.

Comment: I'm trying to add new card list to existing one.The fetch request happen after I send link of new articles.So it happens after `onPressSubmit`.I want to dynamically render new components.How do I do that?Please help..Stuck with this for days..pleasee

Comment: This is the screenshot  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DXxE.png . When i paste new links and click on `tick icon` I want to add new card list to existing one.How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

give res a init value like [] or judge res is undefined in your render function